# How to fix footers height in HTML?

Tags: html, css

Hello i have question when i'm watching on my bigger monitor my height is not correct my height in footer so i need help?
when i'm watching on my bigger monitor is like :[image]

and on small monitor is like : [image]

btw i need fix that lines

Comment: Show us your code, both HTML and CSS

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: my footer code [link](http://pastebin.com/dge5Wp3X)
my footer CSS [link](http://pastebin.com/iGc6dZMD)

Comment: can you tell me that how you want your footer look like?

Comment: i want looks like same as mines [link](http://www.part.lt/perziura/9aed9f6f6a74dac9c9dbce0830a2b071704.png)
but i want to fix lines height for all sizes i want same.

Comment: you want to align the dark green side lines?

Comment: yeah i want to make that line to align to dark green not light green

Comment: i want to make same as this [link](http://www.part.lt/perziura/cd6b3cba53949144be6f509b2b13a344421.png)

Comment: still working on your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

https://jsfiddle.net/b2avu1h9/3/

I have edited this part

```
.column{
width: 20%;
//height:50px;
height: 90px !important;
float:left;
border-right:3px solid #6bae6b;
padding-left:15px;
}
```

Comment: glad to know. really worked hard on that but issue was so small.

Comment: yeah glad you was here to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
#footer {
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:30px;
   width:100%;
   background:#999;
}
```

Comment: try this .footer {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
}